# Proper way to install pavers that will be under an outdoor shower?

Tags: shower, outdoor, pavers

What is the proper way to install pavers that will be under an outdoor shower with a drain?

My situation:  I just bought a house that has a wonderful outdoor shower on the side of the paver patio.  6 month of use and Im seeing mold and the beginning of insects, discoloration from the soap, etc.  The pavers arent sealed or anything and I now know that didnt do anything special for the shower potion of pavers.  no plastic, sealant, anything.  Up till now, Ive been doing band-aid solutions and I want to fix the problem for longer than a month.

What can I do now to make sure I stop the pavers from getting WAY out of control?